# How to add a border for a frame in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Below is my UI. I am trying to add a border for the frame.

But I am *not* getting any information on how to add a border. How can I do it?

[image: Border as in the image]

Answer (score 25):

The requested feature is not called a border in Tkinter. It is called a highlight.

To get the above request, set `highlightbackground="black"` and `highlightthickness=1`.

(The border is the empty space reserved around the frame)
Additional information is available [in documentation](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/frame.html).)

Comment: The doc link (at the effbot site) appears to be not viable: "effbot.org is taking a break. We’ll be back, in some form or another." These two options could use better explanation -- i.e. which widget are these options added? Using a frame I get _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-highlightbackground". I'm requesting since this "answer" appears to be the most upvoted for this question.

Comment: I have to agree with Harlin, this doesn't appear to work for me at all. I think this answer needs updating

Answer (score 6):

In the documentation, look at the styles you can apply to a frame using Tkinter: [Tkinter Frame Widget](https://web.archive.org/web/20200318080632/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/frame.htm)

Here is how you do this:

```
import tkinter as tk
#tk.Frame(master, **config-options)

my_frame = tk.Frame(parent_widget, borderwidth = 1)
```

Answer (score 5):

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
frame1 = Frame(root, highlightbackground="blue", highlightthickness=1,width=600, height=100, bd= 0)
frame1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

- change the options accordingly
- **highlightbackground** is used to change the color of the widget in focus
- **highlightthickness** is used to specify the thickness of the border around the widget in focus.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried like:

```
frame_left = tk.Frame(window, width=100, height=360, bg="blue", borderwidth=1, relief=tk.RIDGE)
frame_left.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
frame_right = tk.Frame(window, highlightbackground="green", highlightthickness=10, width=100, height=100, bd=0)
frame_right.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
```

See the link below to for what the output of the above code looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkgAm.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use *relief* and *borderwidth* like this.

```
from tkinter import *    
root = Tk()
frame1 = Frame(root, width=400, height=660, bg="White", borderwidth=1, relief=RIDGE)
frame1.place(relx=0.7, y=80)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do they have a name in Python? Named parameters? Perhaps add (non-naked) specific links to *documentation* for those two? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 0):

Please use `root.config()`

```
root.configure(background= "#ffffff", borderwidth =2)
```